# such that nobody would see him

Tags: clauses, resultative

a. He went into the room such that nobody would see him.

b. The wind blew such that the vase on the window ledge was knocked over.

In (a), 'such that' expresses intention. His intention was not to be seen.

In (b) 'such that' expresses result. The wind doesn't intend to knock the vase over. It is something that happened.

Would you say 'such that' has been used correctly in both cases?

I don't find the sentences very natural, but they seem grammatical to me.

Comment: "Such that" expresses manner, same as "in such a way that", but it's not very common or idiomatic outside a few specific contexts (e.g. mathematics books). Where did these examples come from?

Comment: I cannot say why, but I feel that this *such* is more naturally applied to nouns than to verbs; in both sentences I would replace *such* with *so*.

Answer (score 1):

"Such that" tends to be used more in a *passive* sense, i.e., not willful. The seconds example, "The wind blew such that the vase on the window ledge was knocked over," would be common in colloquial English.

Where there is *intent*, as in the first example, it might be more frequently seen as "He went into the room *so* that nobody would see him," or "He went into the room *in order* that nobody would see him."

You might check [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) for the relative frequency of usage.

Comment: I find neither sentence natural. Most people would say _The wind blew so hard_ or _was so strong that the vase... was knocked over_.

Comment: @KateBunting - The first use is perfectly natural - but only under very limited circumstances. It might well be used if the wind had to blow from a very specific direction at a specific speed to knock the vase over. I agree that it's not natural in general.